# Resolve/Replace Variables in text-file

Tags: variables, resolve

I work with files like this:

```
$a = 5 
$b = 7
test= $a + $b
test1 = QX("cp $a $b")
```

Is there any way to create a text-file where all variables are resolved and printed out? So it would look like:

```
$a = 5
$b = 7
test= 5 + 7
test1 = QX("cp 5 7")
```

Thank you!